# How to extend Spree::Adjustable::Adjuster?

Tags: spree

I’m trying to extend Spree::Adjustable::Adjuster as documented in the guide (http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/adjustments.html). The directions aren't to hard to follow and I followed them to a T but I'm getting the following error:

```
`<module:Adjuster>': uninitialized constant Spree::Adjustable::Adjuster::Base (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Spree are you using?

This feature was added in 3.1.

https://github.com/spree/spree/blame/3-1-stable/core/app/models/spree/adjustable/adjuster/base.rb

https://github.com/spree/spree/blame/master/guides/content/developer/core/adjustments.md#L99-L146

Comment: Well that explains it I'm on 2.3.1